# Parsing a Web Page's Source given URL

Tags: php, parsing, url

How do you parse a certain web page's source code, given the URL? I'd like to find from the source code the author, title and when it was last modified.

My idea is to parse the source code with file_get_contents(). Then, for the author, I'd look inside the source code for < meta name="author" content="[...]" > and then extract what's in content. For the title, I'd look for < title >[...]< /title > and extract whats inside. I'm not sure what I would do for finding when it was last modified.

Would these ways work? Are there better ways?

Comment: How you want to parse it depends on what you want to do with it. PHP's [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) gives plenty of options for parsing, and manipulating HTML and XML. You can use `file_get_contents` or curl to retrieve the page.

Comment: I'd like to find the title, the author, and when it was last modified.

Comment: That varies widely between web pages--you'd need to give a sample of the pages you're trying to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use file_get_contents.

For example:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.external-site.com/page.php');
```

Then the variable $content will have the contents of the external site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse DOM

Try using parsers like this one: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Use curl instead (it still works when "allow_url_fopen" directive is false and it's more flexible).

To parse the web page source code, use may the DOM library, but you should disable the libxml errors output before loading the HTML content.

Example:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
curl_close($ch);
if( $content === null || $httpCode >= 400 ) {
    die();
}

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$title = null;
$titleNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
if( $titleNodes->length === 1 ) {
    $title = $titleNodes->item(0)->textContent;
}
```